# Liferay 6 - Center the Web Content Display Portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm completely new to Liferay and I finally got my first Web Content Portlet set up and I have it showing a single Web Content Asset. My Asset is just a one sentence message with a picture that's all wrapped inside a single Web Content. When I previewed my Web Content Asset on the control panel it was centered but now that I can see it inside the portlet on my actual site the whole Asset is to the left of the screen. How can I center the Asset to the middle of the screen?

I played around in the configuration/look-and-feel but there isn't anything that simply does this. I saw that I have to use the custom CSS box but my knowledge of CSS is minimal/to-none and from what I know about CSS you have to know the name of the class that you want to apply the attributes to and I do not know the nodes/names of the portlet in which I need to apply center attributes to.

Could someone please provide me with how to center my portlet to the middle of the screen?

Comment: Is your Page Layout is 1 column (100%)?

Comment: When I made it a 1 column layout it fixed the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my page layout to '1 Column' and it centered the portlet.

Comment: Check https://www.liferay.com/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/dragging-and-dropping-portlets to get a hint where the layout columns are when you're dragging and dropping the columns (use the CSS-only version at the end of the article)